# Resolving: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test error in a Maven web application using Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to run a test Maven web application (*.war file) that Inserts data into a mySQL database using tomcat. In the maven project itself I have added all the neccesary dependancies to do this. However when I try and run it on the Tomcat server I get this error:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Companies
```

*"/Companies" is the name of my database.

I assmumed this ment that my dependancies were not being added to tomcat during deployment. Other simular questions suggests to go to "Deployement assembly" to add the maven dependancies.

**However this option is only available in eclipse and am using netbeans to run my project.**

My question is how would I do the same on Netbeans?

Comment: Is the tomcat embedded into the IDE? Or is it external?

Comment: you should also try to run your project independent of an IDE.

Comment: Have you added mysq jdbc driver to your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it is external, I have the tomcat folder on my desktop.

Comment: @asbachb yes I have

Comment: When creating the war file, did you convert to zip and check if the dependencies are present? Probably in `/lib` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide where you want to have the mariadb driver. It could be embedded in the application, then simply add that dependency to your pom (it is a mariadb and mysql driver):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you prefer that dependency to be resolved by Tomcat, simply drop that jar file into the `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` directory.
The advantage is that the responsibility for upgrading mysql in connection with the driver can be delegated away from development.